# Вылетает активити

Tags: java, android, android-sdk, imageview

При переходе из одного активити в другое приложение просто закрывается, если убираю строчку app:srcCompat="@drawable/ach1" то не вылетает. Что не так c этой строчкой?

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/achievfon">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/str_nag"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="80dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="171dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ach1" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

добавил vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true, все равно вылетает

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.testappv1"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'

}
```

Comment: нужно добавить vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true в ваш build.gradle файл. https://overcoder.net/q/53300/%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-app-srccompat-%D0%B8-android-src-%D0%B2-xml-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5-android

Comment: Векторные картинки должны и так работать. Через `android:src`

Answer (score 0):

атрибут `app:srcCompath` используется для внедрения векторных картинок, при условии, что есть его поддержка на уровне библиотек:

Надо добавить в gradle:

```
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

**Update**

Обычные (растровые) картинки вставляются просто:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="171dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:src="@drawable/ach1" />
```

Растровые картинки - это изображение состоит из пикселей, а векторные из векторов (линии, кружочки и т.д.)

Comment: а как мне добавить обычную картинку, если не через app:srcCompath. И чем отличается векторные и не векторные картинки?

Comment: см. апдейт ответ

Comment: не помогло добавление в грэдл vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true